# java random seed for networked game (android and PC)

Tags: java, android, random

I'm making a networked card game that will be played on android and PC.

To handle stuff like shuffling the cards before the game starts and choosing who goes first (and a couple other things like that) I want to use java.util.Random and set a seed on the server and all of the clients to be the same (generated by the server).

This seems to be the easiest way, and more efficient than sending a long message containing the sequence of all 52 cards in the deck shuffled by the server

Is this something I can count on to always generate the same numbers from the same seed on different kind of JVMs/JREs etc (I'm mainly thinking about various versions of android and different versions of dalvik JVM used by android and other things), or should I go the route of shuffling the cards on the server and sending the card list to all the players? (or is there something I can use besides java.util.Random?)

Comment: Why would a client need to know anything about the **entire** deck?  Just curious...

Comment: I wouldn't trust giving the seed to the clients, to be honest. I would rather send only what that client should know about the game's state.

Comment: i guess it doesnt. And if i wanted to prevent cheating itd probably not a good idea. However this is more of a side project and I'd be quite flattered if someone liked my game enough to actually cheat in it... Besides that I already have the human vs ai game built. If I can rely on the same shuffling cards on all clients. I can implement multiplayer by just changing the part where the ai supplies a move, and read the move supplied by the other player instead. (and skip the server having to pass messages around about the deck and cards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since standard javadoc states that [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) must behave the same in all plattforms, you should trust that. Nevertheless, you could let Random appart and code your own algorithm to produce pseudo-random numbers: For example: Imagine a SINE-based function:

double myRandom=amplitude*Math.sin(frequency * sequence)

... where amplitude is the upper bound of your numbering interval (52), and frequency should be a high constant value, non multiple of PI. And sequence should start by a constant offset value and be incremented every time you get a new random value.

Choosing accurately a value for the frequency, you could also ensure that your algorithm won't produce repeated values within a certain number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

According to javadoc, all implementations are required to be the same.

> Java implementations must use all the algorithms shown here for the
>   class Random, for the sake of absolute portability of Java code.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html